# Changing font size in skin

Tags: java, android, libgdx, skin

I am writing a game using libgdx, and I borrowed the skin.json (and related files) from a tutorial.

The font being used (default) was scaling in an ugly manner on denser screens, so I generated by own very large font - and in the game itself, I scale it to a reasonable size (basically I use `BitmapFont.scale`). The font I'm now using is 3 times as large as the previous one.

I changed the reference to which font to use in the skin.json file, and as a result, all my buttons, titles and other things have a massive font being shown.

Is there a way of scaling the font in the .json file? Or anywhere else in the code? Skin doesn't have a `setFont()` functionality, so I can't create a scaled BitmapFont and assign it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Libgdx changed this back in April 2015 so that the set answer doesn't work anymore.  Took a little bit to find the answer, so I thought I'd leave it here for others since this answer pops up first in Google.

```
this.getSkin().getFont("default-font").getData().setScale(0.33f,0.33f);
```

Answer (score 5):

Documentation says that any gets will return a handle to the actual object. So changes will persist.

So I changed the font in skin.json to point to my new font.

Then I used this code

```
this.getSkin().getFont("default-font").setScale(0.33f, 0.33f);
```

To scale the 'default-font' (as defined in the skin.json) to the scale I wanted (in my case its 0.33f)

Answer (score 5):

As of 2017 i had to use

```
skin.getFont("default-font").getData().setScale(0.5f);
```

for future users.