# Libgdx textfield: how to set font size?

Tags: libgdx

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185704/font-size-in-textfield-libgdx)

```
TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = skin.get(TextField.TextFieldStyle.class);
textFieldStyle.font.scale(1.6f);
```

I can't find `font.scale();`

my code

```
username = new TextField("", skin);
username.setMessageText("");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the data from the font first, then you can set the scale. But the recommended way is to create different sizes of the same font.

```
font.getData().setScale(1.0f);
```

Here is a link to same question [Changing font size in skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301964/changing-font-size-in-skin)